# Laravel Backpack - Custom Route File

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to override the default route of laravel backpack by adding role middleware, but cant able to show view file.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:master']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin/users', function () {
        return view('vendor.backpack.crud.list'); //Undefined variable: crud
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've bypassed the controller entirely. In order to solve this, **you need your route to redirect to the controller you're trying to use**, NOT just use the view.

The controller has all the logic. The `list.blade.php` view will not work without the `$crud` variable. That's its entire purpose - to list the entries. And it can't do that without the entries.